# Use Dropbox API with CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, dropbox

Trying to reuse the following Dropbox API code within CodeIgniter. The issue is getting it to work within the constraints of class methods & constuctors:

```
require_once('../dropbox-sdk-1.1.4/Dropbox/autoload.php');
use \Dropbox as dbx;
$accessToken = 'DROPBOX_ACCESSTOKEN';
$dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");
```

Needs to be something like the following, but doesn't like the 'use \Dropbox as dbx' line, amongst others:

```
class Controller_name extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        require_once('../dropbox-sdk-1.1.4/Dropbox/autoload.php');
        use \Dropbox as dbx;
    }

    public function access_dropbox()
    {
        $accessToken = 'DROPBOX_ACCESSTOKEN';
        $dbxClient = new dbx\Client($accessToken, "PHP-Example/1.0");

        $file = 'file.txt';

        $f = fopen( $file, "rb" );
        $result = $dbxClient->uploadFile( "/$file", dbx\WriteMode::add(), $f);
        fclose($f);
    }
}
```

Using the code below I'm getting the following error message:

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Kunnu\Dropbox\Exceptions\DropboxClientException
>
> Message: Error in call to API function "files/upload": HTTP header
>   "Dropbox-API-Arg": path: 'db_backup' did not match pattern
>   '(/(.|[\r\n])*)|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)|(id:.*)'
>
> Filename:
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/codeig-smythes/vendor/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk/src/Dropbox/Http/Clients/DropboxGuzzleHttpClient.php
>
> Line Number: 59

```
$file_path = 'public/sql_backup/db_backup_' .date("Y-m-d"). '.sql';

require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');

$app = new Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxApp(
    'APP_KEY',
    'APP_SECRET',
    'ACCESS_TOKEN'
);

$dropbox = new Kunnu\Dropbox\Dropbox($app);
$dropboxFile = new Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxFile(realpath($file_path));

$file = $dropbox->upload(
    $dropboxFile, basename($file_path), array('autorename' => TRUE)
);
```

Comment: Use statements go before class declaration e.g controller_name and this necessitates the require take place before the fact. I don't really see the need to even use the 'use' statement here as you can just do new \Dropbox\Client(....

Comment: My appended code now works. I'd left out the forward slash: $dropboxFile, "/".$file_path, array('autorename' => TRUE)

Comment: Glad to see it works for you now. I was sleeping until about 10 minutes ago. I am at UTC -08:00 timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with the dropbox API is pretty easy. I use a package found on github:

https://github.com/kunalvarma05/dropbox-php-sdk

I am not using CodeIgniter 3's composer autoload feature. Also, my vendor directory is located at FCPATH.

Since it looks like you want to upload a file, I'll show you that example:

```
$appKey      = '77fgftsb77joj77';
$appSecret   = 'fw77777tspam5y';
$accessToken = 'PMP7777777AAAAAAADFC_6JI7777777hY8xYhO7777777MJkpCKbBv';

if( is_file( $file_path ) )
{
    $file_path = realpath( $file_path );
    $file_name = basename( $file_path );

    require FCPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $app = new Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxApp( 
        $appKey, 
        $appSecret, 
        $accessToken 
    );
    $dropbox = new Kunnu\Dropbox\Dropbox($app);
    $dropboxFile = new Kunnu\Dropbox\DropboxFile(
        $file_path
    );
    $file = $dropbox->upload(
        $dropboxFile, 
        '/backups/website/' . $file_name, 
        [
            'autorename' => TRUE
        ]
    );
}
```

Comment: This looks good Brian, but I'm getting an 'uncaught Exception' error (code above).

Comment: Could you please share your autoload.php file?

Comment: @JackSparrow, there are no modifications to my config/autoload.php file. If you're talking about Composer's autoload.php file, that would be specific to the application, so there's no point in showing the contents as part of my answer.